# Ignore quotation marks, numbers, spaces, etc in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I'm sorting products by title using `ORDER BY title ASC`, and get:

```
"Some" title       // "
1 More title       // 1 
Another title      // A
Third title        // T
Yet another title  // Y
```

I'd like to ignore quotation marks and other non-alpha characters as part of the query, so that it would yield:

```
Another title      // A
1 More title       // M
"Some" title       // S
Third title        // T
Yet another title  // Y
```

Is it possible to strip this stuff out with Postgres or pre-treat as part of the query, or would I need another column?

**Update**

This works great: `LOWER(regexp_replace(title, '[^[:alpha:]]', '', 'g')) ASC`

More options here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
order by regexp_replace(title, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')
```

You can also use:

```
order by regexp_replace(title, '[^[:alpha:]]', '', 'g')
```

This is safer for non-ASCII character sets.

Comment: The `'[^[:alpha]]'` doesn't work for me, but first option does

Comment: Looks like it needs to be `'[^[:alpha:]]'` (trailing colon).  Not sure how you know this as it doesn't seem to be in their docs!

Answer (score 1):

use replace

```
 ORDER BY replace(title, '"', '') asc
```

more advance is

```
ORDER BY regexp_replace(title, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the regexp_replace -- that's what I'm going with

Comment: You can check it live here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4080

Answer (score 1):

You can order by string with replaced `"` to empty string. The same for numeric characters.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(title, '"', ''), '1', '') ... ASC
```

Using `regex_replace`:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY regexp_replace(title, '[^A-Za-z]', '', 'g') ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the regexp_replace -- that's what I'm going with